# How do yugoloths propagate (make more of themselves)?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

So from what I understand, the Lawful Evil Devils primarily perpetuate their race by making deals with mortals in exchange for their souls. A mortal who accepts this deal will rise as a lemure in the Nine Hells upon their death (or sometimes a more powerful kind of devil, depending on the deal). Devils also offer these deals to souls that have reached the Fugue Plane upon their death. A soul that takes advantage of such a deal is likely trying to avoid punishment in the afterlife and thinks damnation is better for some reason. That's all well and good.

Chaotic Evil Demons stage raids on the Fugue Plane, capturing souls that Kelemvor's servants can't save or just straight up ripping some souls off the Wall of the Faithless. Those souls become manes in the Abyss. I can't find any mention of a different way demons increase their ranks, but I may be missing some information.

So how do the Neutral Evil Yugoloths make more Yugoloths? There's no mention I can find anywhere of them interacting with the Fugue Plane or the afterlife in any way. Where Devils embody tyranny and structure (deals), and Demons embrace anarchy and wanton destruction (raids), Yugoloths represent selfishness and sociopathy, and it seems unexplained how they come into being.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 20):

### Monster Manual implies that they do not propagate, but they can replenish destroyed yugoloths up to their original number.

I believe there are not a lot of info on Yugoloths in Forgotten Realms specifically. In 5e Monster Manual (p. 311) Yugoloths are artificial creations made by Night Hags:

> The first yugoloths were created by a sisterhood of night hags on Gehenna. It is widely believed that Asmodeus, Lord of the Nine Hells, commissioned the work, in the hope of creating an army of fiends that were not bound to the Nine Hells. In the course of making this new army, the hags crafted four magic tomes and recorded the true names of every yugoloth they created, save one, the General of Gehenna. These tomes were called the Books of Keeping.
>
> [...]
>
> Petty jealousies and endless bickering caused the sisterhood to dissolve, and in the ensuing power grab, the Books of Keeping were lost or stolen. No longer indentured to anyone, the yugoloths gained independence, and they now offer their services to the highest bidder.
>
> [...]
>
> When a yugoloth dies, it dissolves into a  pool of ichor and reforms at full strength on the Bleak Eternity of Gehenna. Only on its native plane can a yugoloth be destroyed permanently.
>
> [...]
>
> When a yugoloth is permanently destroyed, its name vanishes from every Book of Keeping. If a yugoloth is **re-created by way of an unholy ritual requiring the expenditure of souls**, its name **reappears** in the books.

The Monster Manual implies that it is possibly to recreate destroyed Yugoloth by performing an unholy ritual, which requires performer to procure souls themselves.

Comment: Yugoloths, where permanent just isn't permanent enough.

Comment: Interesting. That's kind of badass that there's a set number of Yugoloths, but who performs the ritual? Night hags, or other Yugoloths? In addition, it kind of seems like a pain in the ass to do that for each dead Yugoloth, since it requires multiple souls to be expended and Yugoloths die all the time serving as mercenaries in the Blood War. Seems like their numbers would be kind of under threat due to this inconvenience.

Comment: Wait, just realized that Yugoloths can only die on Gehenna (or Hades?), so they probably very rarely if ever actually die, since I don't think the Blood War is fought there that often.

Comment: @Antarctika "Can only permanently die on its own plane" is a trope you will see *a lot* in D&D, which is why so many extraplanar entities can afford to be reckless away from home.